# How do I get rid of this seam on the bottom of the lip?

Tags: mesh, vertices, edges, sculpting

I've been going mad trying to fix this. I have a seam that wont conform and become more organic with the face. I've tried sculpting it, but it deforms a lot and the seam becomes more noticeable. Any idea on how to fix this? This is the retopologized version of my character. Let me know if there is anything I can do to make this process easier. I'm running blender 2.83.3. Here is a front and interior picture to help (with the seam circled in red).

[image]

[image]

Comment: It;s hard to tell because I can't see your topology, but are there 2 edges very close together in that section.

Comment: Just as I posted this, I figured it out after reading your comment. There were some vertices not connected that created the crevice. Thanks for the tip Chris, without it, I wouldn't have thought of it.

Answer (score 1):

There are hidden vertices that overlapped during the sculpting phase, resulting in a crevice that was overlooked. Merging the vertices fixed this issue.